# Only static members can be accessed in initializers flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

im new to Flutter, I have a stateful class here

```
class _EmployeeSeekerScreenState extends State<EmployeeSeekerScreen> {
  static var _userID;
  void initState() {
    getID();
    super.initState();
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    StreamData(
      document: _userID,
      collection: 'users',
    ),
    Text(
      '2',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
  ];
}
```

and I have a method called getID(), here's the code

```
 getID() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      _userID = user.uid;
    });
  }
```

I have successfuly get the value of userID, however it turns out to be null value, when I assigned it to document variable in my StreamData widgets.

**My question is how to pass userID value to my _widgetOptions document variable?**

Comment: why _userID is static ?

Comment: if using String variable it turns out to be Only static members can be accessed in initializers flutter, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem by changing widget getter into this

```
 List<Widget> get _widgetOptions =>
```